# & in SCSS extends issue

Tags: css, npm, sass, node-sass

In my scss code I'm trying to make placeholder like:

```
%input__label {
    color: red;
    &_content {
        color: blue;
    }
}
```

And then extend it:

```
.input__label {
    @extend %input__label;
}
```

When I'm trying to compile that code only input__label compiles, but input__label_content doesn't:

```
.input__label {
   color: red;
}
```

(But for example with pseudo elements - &::after everything works fine)
Why is this hapenning? I'm using node v7.10.1 and node-sass v4.5.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a mixin instead of an extend:

```
@mixin input__label {
    color: red;

    &_content {
        color: blue;
    }
}

.input__label {
    @include input__label;
}
```

The functionality to do it via extends is purposefully disallowed:
https://github.com/sass/sass/commit/face3172930b515ac2040e450d4db3ffe01c31b5

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. Thanks so much! =)